# Provisional application in UK

Tags: provisional-application, priority, uk

According to the official [documentation](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/provisional-patents), the equivalent of provisional applications in the UK is to file an application without requesting search or examination, and subsequently, within 12 months, submit a related priority application for that invention.

What isn't clear in that documentation is whether this initial application needs to contain the claims or simply full disclosure in form of description + related work + figures is sufficient.

If that's the case, would there be any benefit in adding claims to the initial application, or would it be more convenient to add them only to the priority application?

And related question: if an inventor would like to take this route to get to a PCT application, would the deadline be 12 months from the initial filing? If so, going *provisional* with the UK filing would mean that the patent would still have to be evaluated by the time of the PCT application, or how much time would the applicant have to apply for PCT from the initial application in the UK?

In this case, what would be the correct procedure and timeline to go 1. provisional 2. final 3. PCT 4. individual countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the requirements of UK's IPO when it comes to according a filing date, which is the relevant act for generating a priority right. At the EPO you can follow the same procedure suggested in the documentation you refer to, i.e. file an application but not proceeding further with it, and for [according a filing date all you need is](https://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/guidelines/e/a_ii_4_1.htm):

> (a) an indication that a European patent is sought;
>
> (b) information identifying the applicant or allowing the applicant to
> be contacted; and
>
> **(c) a description or reference to a single previous application.**

The EPO is very explicit, you just need a description to accord a filing date. So the addition of claims is entirely up to you, and in no way that will influence the generation of a priority right. Perhaps at the UKIPO it is the same, but I do not know.

Should filing claims not be necessary, then adding them in that 'provisional' strictly speaking has no real advantage if the description is well-written. Notwithstanding, I personally like to have claims drafted and have them written somewhere in the application, just because they provide explicit support for claim amendments later on. The dependencies of the claims are very useful in that regard, but if you draft the description carefully you can have the very same support even without claims.

Regarding the other question, the provisional will start the priority timer. At the end of the 12-months period from the provisional you must file every application you want to file that is to benefit from that priority. So if you ultimately want to have a PCT application with a valid priority, that PCT shall be filed no later than 12 months after the provisional.

The provisional UK application will not be examined or searched by the patent office, so you will not have any patentability opinion by the time you file the PCT. If you want a patentability opinion you need to pay the fees, but I do not know if the UKIPO is committed to draw up a search report like the EPO does in 6 months.

Comment: @the Europeist: thanks for the clear answer. My main interest in going UK first is in the relatively inexpensive fees. And, also to buy some time in order to wait for the upcoming EU Unitary Patent when it comes to coverage in the EU. I'm not very knowledgeable on the matter, but from what i could read, it would be a lot of convenience both in practical terms and in economic terms.

So with this approach would it be correct to say
Month 0: file UK provisional 
Month 12: progress UK, file PCT
Month 30: file EU unitary patent (and other countries of interest) ?

Comment: @Pa_ Not sure what you mean by 'progress UK'. Other than that, yes, PCT at month 12 at the latest, and you can enter into EP regional phase up to month 31 (you can delay it by approx. 3 months paying some additional fees). I'm not very optimistic about Unitary Patent, I think it will still take some years. Not everyone sees UP as positively as you do, depending on where you want to protect the invention it will be more expensive than the regular EP, and if it gets revoked at the Unitary Courts you lose protection in all States.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite You have the same benefit with the pseudo-provisional. It is a regular filing but it doesn't cost you a single penny. You must file a non-provisional so to speak at month 12 at the latest, so the 20-year term starts at that time. But if you pay fees in the first application (say EP), you get a search report at month 6, you can abandon that application and file the definitive application (e.g. EP, PCT) and get the search fee reimbursed. That provisional de facto will cost you less than 200USD and you get a search report during the priority year.

Comment: thanks for this interesting suggestion. You saying that the most cost-effective strategy to buy time is to file a EU patent application and pay the search fee to get the search result, but then drop it (how?) and file a PCT priority application instead using the initial application to claim priority?
And then at month ~30, for EU do what? file a new EU application? or how would it work at this point?
And a related question: during the initial window (before PCT priority application): would it be possible to amend the application if applicants want to make changes?

Comment: @Pa_ It all depends on your interests. If all you want to do is buy time at the minimum cost, you file the 'provisional' UK or EP without paying any fees, file the PCT 12 months afterwards, and enter from the PCT into the European regional phase at month 31. If you want to have an opinion about your invention (novelty, inventive step, clarity, sufficiency of disclosure), you file the EP first paying taxes, get the search report, and then file the PCT.

Comment: @Pa_ Very limited amendments in the description are possible. The PCT is a brand new application, so you can file that PCT with different contents, but not amend it afterwards. That is why a European Search Report is so useful at month 6 or 7, because if there are problems in your original EP application maybe you can fix them when filing the PCT.

Comment: @ the Europeist:
thanks again for the very useful explanation and suggestions.
I was checking the fees, and would it be correct to say that 'provisional' UK with an opinion and search is substantially cheaper than EU application? just checked EPO fees, and they ask 1000+€ for the search alone.

Comment: @Pa_ I do not know what the cost is in a UK application, whether they are committed to provide a search report in 6 months, and whether you can get the international search fee refunded in the PCT.

Comment: @ The Europeist About your suggestion for buying time at the cheapest cost: would replacing the initial UK or EP application with US application be substantially doing the same?

Comment: @Pa_ Yes it would. Let me be clear though, I have not suggested "buying time". Search reports properly drawn up are a precious tool for defining your patenting strategy and improving your patent application. You want to have such search reports as early as possible to have a better sense of what problems your application might have or whether your invention is patentable. If you get a bad search report or the later you receive the search report the worse position you will be in, sometimes you lose applications for that reason alone, and usually you spend more money in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. so technically the above strategy could be amended by adding an extra 220£ or 375$ (if going through UKPTO or USPTO respectively), for having the search and examination done asap, while leaving the rest of the timely approximately intact? (btw from the answer below i understand UKPTO is not an option anymore for EU residents, as they now require UK address)

Comment: @Pa_ I don't think the USPTO is committed to provide you with a search report or an office action within the priority year, so not sure if this statement «for having the search and examination done asap» is accurate if you are relating asap to priority year. But it does not matter from which country your priority application is (unless from a rather uncommon country), you can file the PCT at month 12 and enter the national/regional phases at month 30/31. I have no clue regarding the requirements for filing at UKIPO, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

As there is no provisional filing in UK, you have the (nice) option to file a patent and not pay for it. If you do that before 31 March 2021 the cost will be £60, after that date it will be £75 when you decide to pay for the Search £150 and Sustantive examination £100 after the 12 months of the filing date.

When you file (and don't pay) you do not need to include claims nor abstract, you can send that latter (12 months limit)

https://www.gov.uk/patent-your-invention/apply-for-a-patent
https://www.gov.uk/patent-your-invention/after-you-apply

But if your plans are to go latter via PCT I would recommend you to go directly without middle steps.

If you want to save money on the PCT search report you have to add someone to the application (applicant of convenience) to increase your ISAs options (International Search Authorities) because if you are an UK citizen living in UK your only ISA available is EP (One of the best/Most expensive).

The search report fees goes from 34 USD (India) to 2091 USD (EP/AT/ES/FI/SE/TR/XN/XV)

https://www.wipo.int/export/sites/www/pct/en/fees.pdf

Further savings can be obtained on the international filing fee depending on the applicant nationality and residency.

Also, if you are short on money you can file the PCT and not pay the search fee to the ISA, the application is still valid to enter on the national stage.

https://www.wipo.int/pct/en/texts/articles/a17.html

```
(b)  The national law of any designated State may provide that,
where the national Office of that State finds the invitation, referred
to in subparagraph (a), of the International Searching Authority justified
and where the applicant has not paid all additional fees, those parts of 
the international application which consequently have not been searched 
shall, as far as effects in that State are concerned, be considered 
withdrawn **unless a special fee is paid by the applicant to the 
national Office of that State**.
```

I won't recommend you not to pay the search but to find an indian friend :-)

Further sources:
https://www.neifeld.com/pubs/WhichROAndISAShouldYouSelectWhenFilingPCT.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I am not UK national nor i live in UK. I realize that the advice to submit a ready-for-search-and-evaluation application is the best idea. Provided this, is a UK-application-first still the best strategy? Or would applying for a US patent directly be as expensive and provide some additional benefit? (also in the light that eventually i want to file PCT).

Comment: Both UK and US allow you to file directly ("pro se") using no agents or middle mans, but UK ask you for a local address located in UK, Gibraltar or the Channel Islands, you can obtain that with a provider or friend. In the US you don't need that but you need a longer process to have access to the private PAIR (notarize a form and send it to the USPTO by postal Mail) and pay $125 for the provisional patent. You could obtain a PO box in UK for free (for example ukpostbox) and only pay for the received letters (if any) (To be continued...)

Comment: So, if you are short on money go to UK first and don't pay anything. You will obtain a 12 months time (Paris Convention) to file in other countries or a PCT (you can file a PCT by yourself directly at WIPO.INT with no middlemen). But you can also file a PCT first and obtain those 12 months and another 18 (Total 30) to file in almost any country and taking in account that certain nationals get a discount of 90% when filing the PCT, you can end filing a PCT for only 150 USD (with search report included) saving tons of money.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I quickly googled about it and found this: https://www.wipo.int/export/sites/www/pct/en/fees/fee_reduction.pdf

Does it mean the discount applies to either those who are born in one of those countries (or are nationals by blood), AND to those that are both residing in and have the passport of one of those countries? (there are 3 ands in the first sentence and i'm not sure how to interpret)

Comment: Also, according to https://www.uspto.gov/patents/basics/international-protection/patent-cooperation-treaty/pct-fees-us-dollars the reduction applies only to the handling fee?

Comment: By blood or not ( maybe except if you are stateless ) a national (only persons) of the first table can enjoy that 90% discount, a national can be living in another country of the said table but not in another country not present in that table. The second table includes Persons or Legal Entities (for example a company) from any of country listed in that second table will enjoy the discount. You are not required to have or show a passport when submitting your patent application to the international bureau, they assume your residency by the address you declared and the nationality declared

Comment: The process of submitting by yourself at Wipo.int is much easier than any office I had saw, there is no requirement of local address, agent, lawyer, submission of notarized document or waiting time, even the language can be one of many aceptable. You will need to provide the application in a language that is accepted by the ISA you choose.
The reduction of the Fee applies to all except the ISA search fee, and in that case there are some ISA with fee reduction for natural persons, but the best is to reach the ISA that fit your current needs.

Comment: If you save money now (choosing for example India as ISA for the search report) when you enter on the national stage the offices most probably will be more suspicious of the quality of the search. If you choose the EP for as the ISA you will save money when you enter on the "regional" stage with EPO as you won't pay any search fee again. It depends on your factors and current situation, also the kind of invention and the way you draft the claims

Comment: thanks for the clarification! I am afraid i won't qualify for such discount, but going straight through WIPO sounds nevertheless quite convenient. I was considering USPTO as ISA, if i understand https://www.uspto.gov/patents/basics/international-protection/patent-cooperation-treaty/pct-fees-us-dollars the fee for micro entity (= private individual) seems high but acceptable (about 545$ for search and 65$ for transmittal), although i'm not sure what International filing fee (1453$) is and when that is due

Comment: @Pa_ - not all private individuals are micro entities, there is an income limit or employment by a college/university. The fees you are talking about seem to be for US as RO. ISA is then another choice, and fee.